Vcpkg + cmake + pybind issue "Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>"
I found out about vcpkg earlier and its seems interesting, but leak of easy to use.
As I understand, after a day of investigations, vcpkg pybind11 goes with vcpkg Python. But when I start a simple program, its aborted and the following output occur  Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>.
Its a known issue, but not for vcpkg Python. And I have no idea why? It is impossible to set path to vcpkg Python.
I'm glad for any idea or insight into.
Straightforward way are perfectly worked:
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(Python3 3.13 COMPONENTS Development REQUIRED)

include_directories(pybind11/include)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)

add_executable(python_embedded_run main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(python_embedded_run PUBLIC pybind11::embed)


For anyone searching for this issue - vcpkg python is broken.
Im trying to include lib without vcpkg and its work. Amazing c++ lib manager ...
